# Parsing the datetime field in Site.com for pick lists

Tags: picklist, datetime, site.com, data-repeater

I am creating pick lists that contain months and years on an event list page in Site.com. The page brings in data for the events using a data-repeater. One of the fields being used is datetime which is formatted in the following manner: Sat Apr 05 00:00:00 GMT 2014. I need to parse both the month and year from the date string. How can I do this in Site.com?

I have already added javascript for the onchange event for the select box so the page will be updated according to the new URL. I have also created filters in the data-repeater using the url query string option. If I have a pick list on another field, such as "category", it works great. However, the datetime field is not straight forward so I need help parsing the month and year.